# Document won't load into iframe with changed, but proper, name

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe

What I'm trying to achieve is being able to load contents of href in to one of three iframes, by changing thier names via java.

The problem is: Chrome will always load contents into first iframe, ignoring it's name change, this problem does not occur in Firefox.

```js
function change_name()
{
document.getElementById('frame1').name = "#" ;
document.getElementById('frame2').name = "main_frame" ;
};
```

```css
.frame {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="frame1" name="main_frame" class="frame"></iframe>
<iframe id="frame2" name="#" class="frame"></iframe>
<iframe id="frame3" name="#" class="frame"></iframe>

<input type="submit" onclick="change_name()" value="change iframe name"/>
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com" target="main_frame">load page into iframe</a>
```

jsfiddle demonstrating what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/514y7v4m/1/
Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stumbled upon this link: http://help.dottoro.com/ljbimuon.php

After some modification of your script, i believe this could be the solution. Changing the contenWindow.name instead of name alone seems to do the trick.

```
function change_name() {
    var one = document.getElementById('frame1');
    one.contentWindow.name = "#";
    console.log("The name is: " + one.name);
    console.log("The name of the window: " + one.contentWindow.name);

    var two = document.getElementById('frame2');
    two.contentWindow.name = "main_frame";
    console.log("The name is: " + two.name);
    console.log("The name of the window: " + two.contentWindow.name);
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm, plus it's quite easy solution. Thanks again.